# Facebook fails to retrieve Joomla 4 images, if the filename is not ASCII?

Tags: facebook, joomla

Some background:

In a controversial change, Joomla 4 encodes image metadata in the image url. For example, instead of:

`/images/articles/testImage.jpg`

it saves

`/images/articles/testImage.jpg#joomlaImage://local-images/articles/testImage.jpg?width=400&height=400`

This isn't a recent change, it goes back to [2021](https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/issues/35871) at least

This shouldn't cause any issues, and it indeed doesn't (for "normal" filenames).

However, I just noticed that if the filename contains non-ASCII characters, for example Greek: "εικόνα1.jpg", then even though the image is displayed properly, Facebook fails to grab it, and returns `net:ERR_HTTP2_PROTOCOL_ERROR 200`.

Tested via https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug and confirmed the case for Greek characters. An example of the failed encoding that Facebook chokes on (sitename changed to "samplesite.gr" for privacy reasons. The [h] in https is on purpose to prevent linking in stackoverflow):

`[h]ttps://z-p3-external.fath7-1.fna.fbcdn.net/emg1/v/t13/14286829027119499094?url=https%3A%2F%2Fsamplesite.gr%2Fimages%2Farticles%2Flogos%2F%CE%BB%CE%BF%CE%B3%CF%8C%CF%84%CF%85%CF%80%CE%BF_8317c.png%23joomlaImage%3A%2F%2Flocal-images%2Farticles%2Flogos%2F%CE%BB%CE%BF%CE%B3%CF%8C%CF%84%CF%85%CF%80%CE%BF_8317c.png%3Fwidth%3D885%26height%3D233&fb_obo=1&utld=samplesite.gr`

Original url:

`[h]ttps://samplesite.gr/images/articles/logos/λογότυπο_8317c.png#joomlaImage://local-images/articles/logos/λογότυπο_8317c.png?width=885&height=233`

I'm not sure if this a Joomla issue (meaning it should do some encoding on non-ASCII filenames) or a Facebook crawler issue. I can solve it via force-removing the metadata from the generated `og:image` tag, but I'd rather confirm that this is a bug on either Joomla's end or Facebook's first.

Comment: The file name itself should definitively be encoded in the URL path. Not sure why this would depend on the _hash_ though.

Answer (score 0):

I think this issue with Facebook is not just because on non-ASCII characters.
I don't use only ASCII characters, but Facebook ignores the image in the article, I think because of this `?width=400&height=400`, which is added by Joomla.
I might be wrong, but if I use the same image and use another system to make a post to Facebook, then the post apears correctly.

Comment: Could you please be more specific with the solution? With your answer, it is not clear if it helps resolving the issue and then I'd rather put it to comment